# Как сделать архитектуру сворачивающего меню профиля как в инстаграм?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

В общем увидел такую классную штуку в инстаграме (а точнее во вкладке профиля), что при скролле в низ, у нас липнет к верху `AppBarLayout`. А потом когда скрол доходит до `TabLayout` то он липнет к нижней части `AppBarLayout`. Подскажите как это реализовать. Все мои попытки были четны.

Я объяснил как мог, поэтому если вы что-то не поняли из моего вопроса, я его дополню. Заранее спасибо.

Вот что мне нужно, заранее извиняюсь за гиф маленького размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что сделал я но оно не работает. Скролиться только то что находиться в `ViewPager` всё остальное статично.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/ColorAppBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_drawer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/ColorAppBarCard"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:rotation="180"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings"
                    app:tint="?attr/ColorItem" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/ColorAppBarCard"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Menu"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="?attr/ColorText1"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/ColorAppBarCard"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search"
                    app:tint="?attr/ColorItem" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctl_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/abl_menu"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="1.5dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?attr/ColorItem" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ctl_menu"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/ColorAppBar" />

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [эту ссылку](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Android-Instagram-Clone)

Comment: @AndreyMihalev к сожаленью в этом примере, данная функция тоже не доступна